# CURL command with --data-raw JSON, Unexpected character error

Tags: json, curl

Hi I need to send JSON format through the CURL command but I am getting an error.

```
curl --request POST "https://app.io/api/graphql?accountId=Xzg" --header "x-api-key: WHpnV=" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw "{applications(limit: 2) {nodes {name}}}"
```

So the problematic part is data-raw, although I have checked it online it's Valid JSON.

```
--data-raw "{applications(limit: 2) {nodes {name}}}"
```

Response:

```
{"metaData":null,"resource":null,"responseMessages":[{"code":"DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE","level":"ERROR",
"message":"Unable to process JSON Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): 
    was expecting double-quote to start field name","exception":null,"failureTypes":[]}]}
```

I tried different ways how I could change this request data but without success. Can someone please assist me how I should change this query which was definitely generated as the proper one from some app. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce StackExchange.  Please [edit] your post to describe how your question is related to Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your attempting to send the query via JSON (https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/introduction/http-methods) and so you need to wrap it as a query?

```
--data-raw '{"query": "{applications(limit: 2) {nodes {name}}}" }'
```